# Fully qualified machine name Java with /etc/hosts

Tags: java, inetaddress, fully-qualified-naming

I am trying get the fully qualified name of my machine (Windows 7 x64) in Java. On my machine, I've updated the c:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file such that it has an entry like this:

```
10.44.2.167 myserver myserver.domain.com
```

All our systems have an entry in the \etc\hosts file (in the above format) which I cannot change.

The following code always returns "myserver" and I am never able to get the fully qualified name.

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
String fqName = addr.getCanonicalHostName();
```

How do I achieve this in Java?

Thanks,

Shreyas

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty way to do [this](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Local.html):

```
try {
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();

// Get IP Address
byte[] ipAddr = addr.getAddress();

// Get hostname
String hostname = addr.getHostName();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
}
```

Comment: on my machine this still returns the short name.

Comment: Try [this link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName()) to retrieve the fully qualified host name by calling getCanonicalHostName()

Comment: getCanonicalHostName() is what I am using but it does not work in my case because of my etc/hosts file.

Comment: Have you tried encapsulating `myserver myserver.domain.com` in quotes?

Comment: This provides only the primary name, not any alias.

Answer (score 2):

from 'man hosts '
/etc/hosts (or windows equivalent) has the following format:

```
ip_address  fully_qualified_name   aliases
```

so in your case, hosts file would look like:

```
10.44.2.167 myserver.domain.com   myserver another_alias
```

When Java does host lookup, if /etc/hosts has an entry, it will grab the first host_name (not the alias)